# Quais os riscos de colocar uma aplicação ASP.NET em um ambiente com Balanceamento de Carga?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, balanceamento-carga

Com relação ao código... existe algum risco que possa afetar minha aplicação a partir do momento que ela trabalhe em um cenário de Balanceamento de Carga?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 1. `Sessions`

*Sessions* são um problema comum em sistemas escritos para uma máquina só que passam a ser executados em ambiente particionado. As primeiras abordagens para o ASP.NET eram bastante falhas, e foram corrigidas com algumas estratégias, como o uso de um **servidor de estados**.

Toda a informação de usuários e informações de navegação deve ficar em uma máquina fora do restante do *cluster*, isto porque manter a sessão entre as máquinas do *cluster* causava inconsistência de informações.

[Este artigo ensina a implementar um esquema de particionamento de sessão para seu site](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/23/ASPNET-Session-State-Partitioning.aspx). A alteração no seu site é mínima, partindo do `Web.config`.

## 2. Lidando com arquivos

Analogamente, podemos dizer que ambientes com balanceamento de carga precisam ter um servidor dedicado a hospedar os arquivos em separado das máquinas que servem um determinado sistema ASP.NET MVC.

O motivo é o mesmo das `Sessions`: evitar inconsistência. Dependendo de como a implementação é feita, há o risco de um arquivo subir para apenas uma das máquinas. A estratégia de replicar os arquivos para as outras máquinas pode parecer tentadora, mas pode gerar ainda mais inconsistências porque, em teoria, não existe um mecanismo que garanta sincronicidade de arquivos dentro do ASP.NET MVC. Claro, ainda podem existir alternativas que garantam a sincronicidade dos arquivos, mas fora da tecnologia e fora dos padrões.

Comment: Só tem problema com as sessões mesmo? Não tem problema de por exemplo... eu salvar um arquivo e ele ficar somente em uma das máquinas, algo do tipo?

Comment: @psNytrancez Este é mais fácil de resolver. Seria o caso de mapear o diretório de arquivos também para uma máquina em separado das aplicações. Se quiser posso aumentar a resposta com isso.

Comment: Acho que seria interessante agregar isso a resposta visto que a ideia é mapear todos os riscos.

Comment: @psNytrancez Veja se está ok, por favor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez além do ASP.net MVC acredito que isso seja verdade em qualquer outra linguagem server-side.

Comment: @gmsantos Verdade. Tentei centrar minha resposta à tecnologia mencionada na pergunta. Não sei como fica o balanceamento de *Sessions* em outras tecnologias.